# Finding an index set so that row sums are positive

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms

Assume $A$ is a $n$-dimensional matrix of real numbers. The diagonal entries are non-negative, and all other entries are non-positive. I would like to find a subset $I \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ of maximum size such that the sub-matrix of $A$ defined by $I$ has positive row sums, for every row. The sub-matrix of course only includes entries $A_{ij}$ such that $i, j \in I$.

Now, this problem generalizes max independent set, so I am not expecting anything great. Just wondering if anything at all, algorithmically, is known about this problem. Even special cases.

Comment: can u please explain why the problem generalizes max independent set. You are asking to find the sub-matrix, so i thought it is in P.

Comment: You could put 0.1 on the diagonal, some large negative number in each entry representing an edge. Then the sub-matrix would only have to contain non-edges to make the row sum positive.

Comment: So your row sum only sums over the index set $I$, right?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih, right.